# How to edit a file dynamically in a running docker container

Tags: docker, nsenter, linux-containers

**Background**

I had build a npm server(sinopia) docker image(https://github.com/feuyeux/docker-atue/blob/master/docker-images/feuyeux_sinopia.md), and in the CMD line, it will run the start.sh every time when the container is generated.

```
CMD ["/opt/sinopia/start.sh"]
```

This shell will create a yaml file dynamically.

```
sed -e 's/\#listen\: localhost/listen\: 0.0.0.0/' -e 's/allow_publish\: admin/allow_publish\: all/' /tmp/config.yaml > /opt/sinopia/config.yaml
```

**Question**

I wish I could edit this config.yaml when the container is running, because I hope the content should be changed on demand.

[image]
[see the snapshot photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRTfR.png)

As shown above, the first line runs a **sinopia** container, and in this container, there's /opt/sinopia/config.yaml. But I don't know how to obtain this running container and edit and check this file.
If I did as the line of **sinopia-ls**, there's a new container runs instead of the before running one.

Thanks guys!

**Answer(details please see below what I accepted)**

```
sudo nsenter --target $PID --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid

root@58075317e47d:/# ls /opt/sinopia/
config.yaml  config_gen.js  start.sh  storage
root@58075317e47d:/# cat /opt/sinopia/config.yaml
```

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26915343/637210

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With docker 1.3, there is a new command [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec). This allows you to enter a running docker:

```
docker exec -it <container-id> bash
```

Comment: From the question asked, the best answer is from nsenter to exec. The docker is growing

Comment: docker exec -it <container-id> bash    this would only work if you have the bash enabled for your docker image , also you can write "/bin/bash"

Answer (score 2):

You named your container, so you can find it using that name.

Then use nsenter ([man nsenter](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html)) to send the command you want to do.

```
nsenter --target $$(docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} <container_name_or_ID>) --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid <cmd>
```

More info and solution on how to write inside of a running container : [If you run SSHD in your Docker containers, you're doing it wrong!](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/)

Comment: If you install using Jerome's instructions in your link then you'll also get the docker-enter script that automates the ugly arguments to nsenter: `docker-enter <container_name>`

Answer (score 0):

you just need to mount the folder using -v as an option. i give an example

1. let's say i have `/home/awan/config.yml` <--- this file is always dynamic must not put it inside container
2. i run my container so i can mount that folder into my container

`#sudo docker run -i -t -v /home/awan:/home/ubuntu/awan ubuntu/14.04 /bin/bash`

3. after that you just edit `config.yml` in your `/home/awan/config.yml` every changes that you applied automaticaly applied inside your docker container (`/home/ubuntu/awan/config.yml`) because you mount it