# How to fix broken kibana docker container

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana-4

I am using elasticsearch 2.3.3 and kibana 4.5.1 versions. I am a new bee for both tools, may be I did somethings in wrong way.

I logged into docker container using `docker exec -it (container_name) bash`. Rather than using `bin/kibana plugin -i own_home -u https://github.com/wtakase/kibana-own-home/releases/download/v4.6.4-3/own_home-4.6.4-3.zip` command to add plugin. because of some security firewall issues I am not able to connect to github from this machine. So, I downloaded the zip file and moved the zip file to docker container and unziped and placed in plugins folder (i thought it would work). after this I ran this command `bin/kibana plugin -l` it was showing own_home, so assumed it is working. I exited from bash shell. I tried to start container it is broken. I am not able to launch the bash shell on container. I followed [fixing broken container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353055/how-to-start-a-stopped-docker-container-with-a-different-command/32353134#32353134) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750748/how-to-edit-files-in-stopped-not-starting-docker-container#32828427) links and went to changed `config.v2.json` file with entrypoint as "/bin/bash". I restarted docker service `service docker restart` after this I launched elasticsearch container. Now looks like easticsearch is showing status as red `1518025537 17:45:37 elasticsearch red 1 1 0 0 0 0 20482 7 20.5s 0.0%` and once i try to start kibana container `docker start -i contianer_name`I get this error

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-02-07T17:51:48+00:00","tags":["fatal"],"pid":10,"level":"fatal","message":"Cannot find module '../../../../src/plugins/elasticsearch/lib/kibana_index_mappings'","error":{"message":"Cannot find module '../../../../src/plugins/elasticsearch/lib/kibana_index_mappings'","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Cannot find module '../../../../src/plugins/elasticsearch/lib/kibana_index_mappings'\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)\n    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)\n    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/kibana/installedPlugins/own_home-4.6.4-3/server/proxy/create_kibana_index.js:2:30)\n    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)\n    at normalLoader (/opt/kibana/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:199:5)\n    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/opt/kibana/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:216:7)\n    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)\n    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)\n    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/kibana/installedPlugins/own_home-4.6.4-3/server/proxy/replace_kibana_index.js:5:28)\n    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)\n    at normalLoader (/opt/kibana/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:199:5)\n    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/opt/kibana/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:216:7)","code":"MODULE_NOT_FOUND"}} FATAL { [Error: Cannot find module '../../../../src/plugins/elasticsearch/lib/kibana_index_mappings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

original config.v2.json file looks like this

```
{"State":{"Running":false,"Paused":false,"Restarting":false,"OOMKilled":false,"RemovalInProgress":false,"Dead":false,"Pid":0,"ExitCode":1,"Error":"","StartedAt":"2018-02-07T13:15:17.103980013Z","FinishedAt":"2018-02-07T13:15:18.633400496Z"},"ID":"3961f2886fd35747cb590d9b3344c52f0fb9074fac820d726eb9cede133c4a07","Created":"2016-06-14T13:09:05.667516205Z","Path":"/docker-entrypoint.sh","Args":["kibana"],"Config":{"Hostname":"3961f2886fd3","Domainname":"","User":"","AttachStdin":false,"AttachStdout":false,"AttachStderr":false,"ExposedPorts":{"5601/tcp":{}},"Tty":false,"OpenStdin":false,"StdinOnce":false,"Env":["PATH=/opt/kibana/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin","GOSU_VERSION=1.7","TINI_VERSION=v0.9.0","KIBANA_MAJOR=4.5","KIBANA_VERSION=4.5.1"],"Cmd":["kibana"],"Image":"kibana","Volumes":null,"WorkingDir":"","Entrypoint":["/docker-entrypoint.sh"],"OnBuild":null,"Labels":{}},"Image":"sha256:298836bc417010b404216d1079dc37532a9c5c19feb8be574975ebd41f096a99","NetworkSettings":{"Bridge":"","SandboxID":"f11ba1c6c9ec5f257722d148696c3bd07ea19347dec73cac62c5033361d805a9","HairpinMode":false,"LinkLocalIPv6Address":"","LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"Networks":{"bridge":{"IPAMConfig":null,"Links":null,"Aliases":null,"NetworkID":"4ffe45a3a571397ad84aa83dd2bc62caecc26ffa11c1bfc651f9378111fcd440","EndpointID":"","Gateway":"","IPAddress":"","IPPrefixLen":0,"IPv6Gateway":"","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"MacAddress":""}},"Ports":null,"SandboxKey":"/var/run/docker/netns/f11ba1c6c9ec","SecondaryIPAddresses":null,"SecondaryIPv6Addresses":null,"IsAnonymousEndpoint":false},"LogPath":"/var/lib/docker/containers/3961f2886fd35747cb590d9b3344c52f0fb9074fac820d726eb9cede133c4a07/3961f2886fd35747cb590d9b3344c52f0fb9074fac820d726eb9cede133c4a07-json.log","Name":"/kibana","Driver":"aufs","MountLabel":"","ProcessLabel":"","RestartCount":0,"HasBeenStartedBefore":false,"HasBeenManuallyStopped":false,"MountPoints":{},"AppArmorProfile":"","HostnamePath":"/var/lib/docker/containers/3961f2886fd35747cb590d9b3344c52f0fb9074fac820d726eb9cede133c4a07/hostname","HostsPath":"/var/lib/docker/containers/3961f2886fd35747cb590d9b3344c52f0fb9074fac820d726eb9cede133c4a07/hosts","ShmPath":"/var/lib/docker/containers/3961f2886fd35747cb590d9b3344c52f0fb9074fac820d726eb9cede133c4a07/shm","ResolvConfPath":"/var/lib/docker/containers/3961f2886fd35747cb590d9b3344c52f0fb9074fac820d726eb9cede133c4a07/resolv.conf","SeccompProfile":"","NoNewPrivileges":false}
```

I took backup of image using `docker commit`. But i am not sure whether my dashboards are stored, I cannot afford to loose any data. How do I fix this container issue?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out and fixed this issue. Index files are huge so elasticsearch is taking time to start. The main issue is with kibana docker container. In config file (config.v2.json file) `docker-entrypoint.sh` is configured to start the container. I used `docker cp`  to copy this script into my system. I added `rm -R (ownhomefolder path)` to the script and copied back to container. I started the container, issue is resolved. I replaced with original script.