# remove file from stopped docker container (without create new image)

Tags: docker

I have simple container with some service.

When I restarting server without stopping this container, I can't start it again.

Error message is:

```
pidfile found, try stopping another running service or delete /var/run/service.pid
```

I know that I can

1. run new container from image and delete stopped one
2. create new image from stopped container and re-run it with new entrypoint. Something like `rm -f /var/run/service.pid && original_entrypoint.sh`

But I want simply do something like

```
docker rm_file container:/var/run/service.pid; docker start container
```

Because it is most simple and fast to start solution.

Isn't here is no way to access container's fs without completely rebuild it? This operation is looking so useful...

Comment: can you mount `/var/run` to some host path when run docker, so when restart you can simply delete file from host?

Comment: @LeiYang Thank you for comment, but not sure if holding temporary files at host is a good idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering by myself using hints from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750748/how-to-edit-files-in-stopped-not-starting-docker-container)

1. Find where directory stored on docker host:

   ```
   export LOCAL_DIR=$(docker inspect -f '{{ .GraphDriver.Data.UpperDir }}' container_name)
   ```
2. Remove file locally:

   ```
   sudo rm -f ${LOCAL_DIR}/run/service.pid
   ```
3. Run container:

   ```
   docker start container_name
   ```

Or all in one:

```
sudo rm -f "$(docker inspect -f '{{ .GraphDriver.Data.UpperDir }}' container_name)/run/service.pid" && docker start container_name
```

Answer (score -1):

I *always* delete the old container and run a new one.  This works consistently with every application and runtime, and doesn't involve trying to figure out how to manually reset the container filesystem to its initial state.  I almost never use `docker start`.

```sh
docker rm container_name
docker run -d --name container_name ...
```

If you're in a context where the old pid file might be left behind (maybe it's in a bind-mounted host directory) you can use an entrypoint wrapper script to clean it up:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
rm -f /var/run/service.pid
exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile, make this script be the `ENTRYPOINT`.  The last line will run the image's `CMD` as the main container process.

```sh
...
COPY entrypoint.sh . # must be executable, may already be there
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"] # must be JSON-array form
CMD same as before
```

(Your question references an `original_entrypoint.sh`; if you already have this setup, edit the existing entrypoint script in your local source tree and add the `rm -f` line in there.)

Comment: Thank you. That is useful information, but your solution suppose to rerun (rebuild) container, and as I said in my question that is no way for me in this time.