# How can i make Running Docker container to Realize with new changes

Tags: docker, containers

Now I have A **running docker Container**, I have a Running Container from

zabbix_server Image , i want to change parameter in /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server

how can This running container about the new changes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit Docker container files from the host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553790/how-to-edit-docker-container-files-from-the-host)

Comment: See also: [Copying files from host to Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31971697/5328069)

Comment: sorry , it is not the same : now i have container from zabbix-server image i want to change some parameters in this running container , how can container know this changes . thank u in advance

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly. You talk about modifying files, not the command ran on the container.

Comment: i edited it , thank u , there is a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a CMD or ENTRYPOINT, you can override it following this link [override ENTRYPOINT or CMD](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-entrypoint-vs-cmd/)

If it's not a CMD or ENTRYPOINT, access to your container using shell after copy your new files:

```
docker cp <yourfile> <yourcontainer>:/path
docker exec -ti <yourcontainer> /bin/bash
```

Comment: docker exec -ti <yourcontainer> /bin/bash : in this command , running container can know the changes , i want to change in /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf , container can know this changes automatically ?