# PhpStorm and Docker: read-only container code

Tags: docker, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using PhpStorm with Docker plugin.

I'm connecting to my docker daemon via "Docker for Windows".

I can view the files from container in editor but I cannot modify them. In VS Code I can modify them. Is it possible to do so in PhpStorm as well, and how?

Comment: Are you running vscode as admin / a user with elevated permissions? People usually run their docker containers as root, (which I don't prefer personally) and you try to access / edit files in it as a normal user,it will cause permission issues.

Comment: Running it as normal user. Tried to run Storm as administrator but problem persists.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible in PhpStorm. A possibility to edit & save files in a container is being worked on, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176734#focus=Comments-27-3565950.0-0.

There are two possible workarounds:

- You can try editing your files with a host editor.

[How to edit Docker container files from the host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553790/how-to-edit-docker-container-files-from-the-host)

- You can try running docker cp command to get the file out of the container, then editing it and copying it back and restarting the container.

[How to edit files in stopped/not starting docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750748/how-to-edit-files-in-stopped-not-starting-docker-container?noredirect=1&lq=1)